# How do you solve angular typescript errors in d.ts files? Specifically msal

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-ad-msal

I am using Msal (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) with the latest angular setup including Typescript 3.1.1 and I get the following error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/msal/lib-commonjs/UserAgentApplication.d.ts(35,9):
error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.
Property 'callBackMappedToRenewStates' must be of type 'any', but here has type '{}'.
```

Looking at the code in the node module I can see the problem but obviously I would rather not edit this file or create a custom typing file just to fix this issue. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tsconfig can take a skipLibCheck property which will skip type checking in all declaration files. Going with this until msal gets fixed - dont really want it as it does silence all errors for all packages.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if you're using the right version of Typescript for this library.

If you are, ignore Typescript errors with `// @ts-ignore` or `any` type declarations, and wait for a fix.

Comment: Yeah they want 2.5.3 whereas I have 3.1.1 so that makes sense - but they seem to have their own tsconfig in the node module and I think thats why my setting "noImplicitAny": false did not work.

Comment: Big thanks for answering, it really helped a lot but I found a 'correct' solution so im going to put my own answer.